# Can I recover Thunderbird e-mails from a recent backup in Xubuntu 16.04 into a recently installed version of Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, backup, email, thunderbird, deja-dup

I worked with Xubuntu 16.04 for some years and tried to upgrade to version 18.04 some time ago. Every week I made a backup with 'deja-dup'.

The upgrade to 18.04 failed and I had to decide installing Xubuntu 18.04 from a live DVD and this worked fine.

I know that all my e-mails are still in the 16.04 backup and my question therefore is how to get these mails into the Thunderbird map of the 18.04 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the folder `~/.thunderbird` from one computer to another. This folder is "hidden" by default (all folders that begin with a `.` aren't shown by default)

Comment: Thank you Kristopher Ives, but this 16.04 folder is overwritten by the upgrade to 18.04, I think. HHarry18

Answer (score 0):

If, when installing the new version, you wiped your home folder, you can restore the ~/.thunderbird folder from your Deja Dup backup.